# Disprove inequality by induction

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction

EDIT: This is the explicit text of the practice problem:

*Find out, by induction, whether for $ n \geqslant 1$, it is true that $n^2 - 3n - 1 \leqslant 0$.*

———

I am learning to use induction. I am asked to prove by induction whether the property $n^2 - 3n - 1 < 0$ holds for all $n\geqslant 1$.

This is obviously false, but I am finding it hard to prove by induction. I am not sure what I am allowed to do.

**Base case:** P(1) = -3 < 0.

**Inductive step:**
Assuming the property is true for $n$, prove that it is also true for $n+1$.

$(n+1)^2 - 3(n+1) - 1 < 0$.

$n^2+ 2n + 1 -3n -3 - 1 < 0$

$n^2 -3n - 1 < -2n + 2$

Since, by inductive hypothesis, $n^2 -3n - 1 < 0$, then $0 \leqslant -2n+2$.
(Is it ok to state it like this?)

Can I just plug a 2 in the inequality and end the proof there?
Or do I have to disprove $-2n+2 \geqslant 0$?

I did not know what to do, so I started a new proof by induction.
I tried to disprove that $-2n + 2 \geqslant 0$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

**Base case:** $P(1) = 0 \geqslant 0$

**Inductive step:**  Assuming the property is true for some $n$, prove that is is also true for $n+1$.

$-2(n+1) + 2 \geqslant 0 $

$-2n -2 + 2 = -2n < 0 $ (for all positive integers)

Is there a more straightforward way to disprove the first property?
Even if there is, would it be correct to do it the way I did?

Comment: Your inequality derection is wrong! The inequality holds in the opposite direction for every $n \geq 4$.

Comment: You are right, but the practice problem asks for what I wrote.

Comment: If you agree with me; why do you try to prove a false statement?

Comment: I thought the practice problem was asking me to disprove by induction (that is why I wrote "Disprove" in the title of the question). But from your responses, I am understanding that it is not possible to disprove by induction? I thought that if I found a contradiction in the induction process, that would be a valid disproof.

Comment: One can disprove the statement "for all $n\geq 1$ one has $n^2-3n-1<0$" by finding an example of an $n$ which satisfies the hypothesis but not the conclusion, i.e. finding an $n\geq 1$ where $n^2-3n-1$ is not negative.  This is called "disproof by counterexample."  All you need is one such $n$, for example $n=10$ (*nothing special about $10$ apart from that it is easy to do arithmetic with and is easy to see works*) we have $n^2-3n-1=100-30-1=69\not\lt 0$

Comment: One does not need to go through the effort of attempting a proof by induction and stopping only after arriving at an invalid inductive step.  Actually, this wouldn't be a valid form of disproof anyways since that might just mean that you approached the inductive step incorrectly but there was a different valid approach to the inductive step that would have worked.

Comment: The practice problem explicitly says: "Find out, **by induction**, whether for all n>= 1,  it is true that $n^2 - 3n - 1 < 0$". So I thought I had to disprove by induction.

Comment: I cannot in good conscience ever recommend to *anyone* to actually use induction as a method of disproof of a universal statement like this.  One could certainly use induction as a method of *proof* if the statement were actually true, or one could do like Famke does below and prove the opposite statement is actually true for all $n\geq 4$, however to *disprove* the original statement this is overkill because the base case by itself in Famke's "disproof" is more than enough to disprove the original statement making everything else written unnecessary.

Comment: If trying to prove something and you run into trouble in the induction step, that might be a clue to you that the statement is false and might lead you to find an explicit counterexample, but running into trouble in the induction step alone is not enough information to successfully disprove anything by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, JMoravitz. I guess they were asking for what Famke did.

Answer (score 1):

you can not prove this by induction, since your inequality is wrong, plug in for example $$n=4$$ this gives $$16-12-1=3>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Excercise: For every $n\geq 4$ show that : 
$$n^2-3n-1 > 0.$$

---

---

Base: $4^2-3 \times 4 -1 = 3 > 0 . \quad \checkmark$

Suppose that the statment holds for $k=n$:

$$n^2-3n-1 > 0;$$ 
on the otherhand we know that:

$$(2n+1)-3=2n-2 \geq 2 \times 4 -2 =6 > 0;$$ 
adding both sides togetter we get :

$$\big(n^2+2n+1\big)-\big(3n-3\big)-1 > 0+0 \ \Longrightarrow \ (n+1)^2-3(n+1)-1 > 0;$$

So we have showed the statement for $k=n+1.$